# How can I apply a different style for page 2, page 3 etc in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to use different styling for other pages in single.php

I'm using this tag to separate my blog posts into several pages:

```
<!--nextpage-->
```

How can I do this in Wordpress?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to add more detail for this question to be coherent.

Comment: Is my problem is how to write , sorry i cant good speack english

Comment: IS this in Wordpress?

Comment: yes this is wordpress im sorry

Answer (score 1):

how to that this

my php in single.php is

```html
<?php get_header();?>
 <main>
<?php get_sidebar() ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div id="post">
     
         <div class="top-single-movie">

         <div class="info"> 
            <h3 class="title" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
   <?php the_title(); ?></a>
   <?php if( get_field('date') ): ?>
          ( <?php the_field('date'); ?> )
            <?php endif; ?> 
   </h3>
   </div>
   
   
            <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) :
            the_post_thumbnail('medium');
            else : 
            echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/img/default.png">';
            endif;
            ?>
   
   </div><!-- End. top-single-movie -->
            
   
            <?php the_content(); ?>
   
   <?php 
 wp_link_pages( array(
  'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'tl_back' ) . '</span>',
  'after' => '</div>'
 ) ); 
?>
   
   <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/php/single/tv-single-rand.php'); ?>
   
   
   </div><!-- End. content-single-movie -->
  

            <p class="tags"><?php the_tags(); ?> </p> 



            <!--?php comments_template(); // Get comments.php template ?-->


            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
            <p> <?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?> </p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <!-- END Loop -->


            <ul class="navigationarrows"> 
            <li class="previous">
            <?php previous_post_link('&laquo; %link'); ?>
            <?php if(!get_adjacent_post(false, '', true)) 
            { echo '<span>&laquo;Previous</span>'; } ?>
            </li>
            <li class="next">
            <?php next_post_link('%link &raquo;'); ?>
            <?php if(!get_adjacent_post(false, '', false)) { echo '<span>Next post:</span>'; } ?> 
            </li>
            </ul><!-- end . navigationarrows --> 

    </div>

 </main>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: Please don't post updates to your question as answers, you should 'Edit' your question. But the answer to your question is, you'll just create a new CSS styling in your stylesheet, and make sure that `body.page-2` is at the start of your CSS rule

Comment: adding `body.page-2{background:blue;}` to my style.css is not worked to me please help thanks

Comment: Sorry, it should be `body.paged-2`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your source code for the other pages (2, 3 etc), you will see there is a new classes added to the `<body>` tag called `paged-2`, `paged-3` etc.

You can apply your own CSS styling based on these new classes, that will only affect those pages.